# Angular components in Drawflow editor

Tags: angular

I am using drawflow library in an angular project v15. I am trying to add angular components into the drawflow editor as nodes. I see this is not possible since the library itself does not support angular components as nodes.

I have tried using web-components but data binding was unsucsessful - I believe it is because of the rendering processes inside angular engine.
My question is has someone successfully managed to integrate angular components or extend the drawflow functionality to do so?
Thanks in advance!